# fab.show() not animated first time after initializing new activity

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

I am using the floating action button (fab) component from com.android.support:design:23.1.0 Library to generate my app's fabs.

But the first time I load a new activity with fab.hide() and try to make the icon visible through fab.show() after a button was clicked, there is no animation for the fab. This happens only the first time after loading a new activity. When I try that multiple times to hide and show the button, it is animated properly.

What is the issue here? It would be a charm to get it animated also right after an activity is loaded.

Java in activity:

```
    fabSend = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabSend);
    fabSend.hide();    


CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener changeChecker = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked){
//                FAB on
                fabSend.show();
            }   else {
//                FAB off
                fabSend.hide();
            }
        }
    };
```

Layout.xml

```
            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fabSend"
                app:borderWidth="0dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
                android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_check_white_24dp" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved this one finally. I designed a new class to handle the reveal animation with a delay. Grab it here, initialize it and you're good to go. I found a pretty similar animation to the standard fab.show() at 50ms delay on it.

```
    public static void showFabWithAnimation(final FloatingActionButton fab, final int delay) {
    fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    fab.setScaleX(0.0F);
    fab.setScaleY(0.0F);
    fab.setAlpha(0.0F);
    fab.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            fab.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            fab.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    fab.show();
                }
            }, delay);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 55):

I've had the same problem. In my fab xml I had `visibility="gone"`, than I tried to show fab from the code by `fab.show()`  - and animation was not working the first time. I've changed xml to `visibility="invisible"` and problem was solved.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Another thing, even if you do not have `visibility="gone"`, you should set `visibility="invisible"`.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to achieve that is by simply setting your Fab's scaleX and scaleY to zero in XML. It is the easiest method and it also leaves your application code clean.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:scaleX="0"
    android:scaleY="0"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to docs:

> android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
>
> public void show()
>
> Shows the button. This method will animate the button show **if the
>   view has already been laid out**.

So, to make it animate the first time you can write you own animation to animate it when it's not currently laid out

```
/**
 * Unlike {@link FloatingActionButton#show()} animates button even it not currently
 * laid out
 * @param fab fab to show
 */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static void show(FloatingActionButton fab) {
    if (ViewCompat.isLaidOut(fab) ||
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        fab.show();
    } else {
        fab.animate().cancel();//cancel all animations
        fab.setScaleX(0f);
        fab.setScaleY(0f);
        fab.setAlpha(0f);
        fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //values from support lib source code
        fab.animate().setDuration(200).scaleX(1).scaleY(1).alpha(1)
                .setInterpolator(new LinearOutSlowInInterpolator());
    }
}
```